# Where to find or install Crystal Reports for VS 2005?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

As the title says really - I'm using Visual Studio 2005 Pro, and I've never used Crystal Reports before, but apparently it should be in the Add New Item list, but its not.

Any ideas how to get this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have unchecked the

Crystal Reports for Visual Studio

section.

You can install this by using

**Add or Remove Features in the Visual Studio 2005 setup.**

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to see if you have installed them - look for "Crystal Reports... For Visual Studio" in "Programs and Features" / "Add Remove Programs"

To install - Your Visual Studio Pro Setup

To use (if you have it, I see you're not pretty sure) - Crystal reports are in the reporting section of "add - new item"